# Fallback for unknown media query in stylesheet include

Tags: html, css, media-queries, darkmode

For a static site I load one of two stylesheets depending a `prefers-color-scheme` media query, as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dark.css"
    media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/light.css"
    media="not all and (prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
```

The downside to this approach is that for browsers that don't support the `prefers-color-scheme` media, *neither* stylesheet will be loaded (queries with unknown elements are always false), so the result is garbage-looking unstyled content.

In this case, I'd like to load `light.css` as a fallback. Is there a good way to do this without Javascript?

Just making one stylesheet unconditioinal like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/light.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dark.css"  media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
```

... doesn't work because the dark scheme may not specify exactly the same attributes for every style as light. It's also not desirable from a performance perspective since now the light stylesheet is redundantly loaded and parsed even in dark mode.